# Screen rotation doesn't work on iOS 5 but is working on iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios5, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

I'm currently having a problem with the screen rotation on iOS 5. On iOS 6, everything works fine but the rotation doesn't work on iOS 5 even though the notification `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` is called.

I'm using `Storyboard` and here's how my `ViewController` is like:

[image]

In order to rotate the screen I use the following methods:

CustomTabBarViewController.mm (`UITabBarController`)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (isLandscapeOK) {
        // for iPhone, you could also return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (isLandscapeOK) {
        // for iPhone, you could also return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown);
    }
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

TabBarItemController.mm (`UINavigationView`)

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}
```

LoyaltyListController.mm (`UIViewController`)

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        [self hideTabBar:self.tabBarController];
        portraitView.hidden = YES;
        landscapeView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        [self showTabBar:self.tabBarController];
        portraitView.hidden = NO;
        landscapeView.hidden = YES;
        [notificationView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, - (notificationView.frame.size.height + 40), notificationView.frame.size.width, notificationView.frame.size.height)];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [(CustomTabBarViewController*)[self tabBarController] setLandscapeOK:YES];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown);
}
```

And here are the screen for iOS 5:

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape: (didn't rotate)

[image]

Here's what it should look like:

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS 5  use `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)`

in iOS 6, its **deprecated** but it wont matter if you use it.
It will only get called in case its iOS 5.0 or below.

**Updated**:
**UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown** is NOT an UIInterfaceOrientation enum type.
Masking is used in iOS 6 to give a mask value to give a combination of orientations you want to support but in iOS 5.

You will have to check if the interfaceOrientaion is either of

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight, UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait or UIInterfaceOrientationPortraightUpsideDown.
```

and return YES or NO based on which all orientations you want to support.

In your case Use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
 /* If you are supporting all, simply return YES,

 if you aren't supporting any return NO, otherwise Use || and check which ones you wanna return YES for.
 In this case you wanna support all except UpsideDown hence use this. */
}
```

Comment: Did you check my source code??? That's exactly what I'm using...

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown);
}`

Comment: Oh I missed it completely. check again! don't use UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown.

You have to only return YES or NO based on value of interfaceOrientaion.
you will have to use || and see which all you wanna support.
in this case since you want to support all except upsidedown, i have written the code that way.

Comment: True, didn't see `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown ` is iOS6 and later :) i'll test it now

Answer (score -1):

you have to return YES for supporting all orientation iOS 5 and previous and its deprecate in iOS and not get called in iOS 6, you have already implemented iOS6 methods correctly

> ```
> - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
> {
>     return YES;
> }
> ```

Comment: Did you check my source code??? That's exactly what I'm using...

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown);
}`